# Combustion analysis of hydrocarbon

Tags: combustion, chemical-formula

Combustion analysis of a hydrocarbon produced 33.01 g CO<sub>2</sub> and 4.84 g H<sub>2</sub>O.

I was asked to find the empirical formula of the hydrocarbon. I used these molar mass values for my calculations:

C - 12.0107

H - 1.00794

O - 15.9994

Here is my work:

```
Molar mass of CO_2 = 12.0107 + 2*15.9994 = 44.0095
Molar mass of H_2O = 2*1.00794 + 15.9994 = 18.01528
```

We now have 33.01g of CO<sub>2</sub> and 4.84g of H<sub>2</sub>O, which means:

```
33.01/44.0095 = 0.750 mol CO_2
4.84/18.01528 = 0.26866 mol H_2O
0.26866*2 = 0.53732 mol H
```

From the calculation we know that the ratio of C to H is 0.750:0.537, which is approximately 3:2. However, the empirical formula C<sub>3</sub>H<sub>2</sub> is not the right answer. Can anyone tell me why I am wrong? Thank you!

Comment: @CaptainToad For future reference: When computing with quantities like $\pu{mol}$, $\pu{kg}$, etc. an equation sign indicates *both* 1) equality of the numbers on the right and left hand side, and 2) equality of the dimensions on the left and on the right hand side. Thus, units (like in $\pu{0.750 mol}$ $\ce{CO2}$ above) do not suddenly appear out of nothing (on occasion, they may yield a dimension less quantity, e.g., Reynold's number, though). Keep track of them (e.g., for [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis#Checking_equations_that_involve_dimensions)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let Hydrocarbon be of form $\ce{C_xH_y}$

Our combustion reaction becomes $\ce{C_xH_y}+(2x+\frac{y}{2})\ce{O_2}\implies x\ce{CO_2}+\frac{y}{2}\ce{H_2O}$

$1$ mole of hydrocarbon produce $x*44g$ of $\ce{CO_2}$

If $\ce{CO_2}$ produced is $33.01g$, then $x=\frac{3}{4}$

Similarly $1$ mole of hydrocarbon produces $\frac{y}{2}$ moles of $\ce{H_2O}$

If $\ce{H_2O}$ produced = $4.84g$, then $\frac{y}{2}=4.84/18\implies y=\frac{1.61}{3}$

Therefore $\frac{x}{y}\approx1.4$ Therefore empirical formula becomes $\ce{C_7H_5}$

Answer (score -1):

0.750//0.53732 = 1.396/1;Hydrocarbon, no heteroatoms, needs even number of H so ratio becomes 2.792/2.  x4 = 11.18/8  X5= 13.96/10  X6= 16.72/12 best fit is 5times so becomes C14H10.  Notice if one rounds off immediately the answer is nice and neat. Don't ever fall into that trap. Next step is MW determination; Rast method or freezing point in benzene or infrared spectrum and mass spec.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? It is the only answer without guessing [ or a MW that fits] or approximating and does show that empirical measurements and/or made up problems do have errors.